# How to read camera make and model with GExiv2 in Python

Tags: python, introspection, pygobject

I'm totally new to GExiv2 or GObject introspection, but managed to figure out how to read the date of the image:

```
from gi.repository import GExiv2

def get_exif_data(filename='DSCN3025.JPG'):
    exif = GExiv2.Metadata(filename)
    print exif['Exif.Photo.DateTimeOriginal']
```

Next I would want the camera make and model, but

```
print exif['Exif.Photo.Make']
```

gives me "KeyError: 'Exif.Photo.Make: Unknown tag'"

Help is very much appreciated here, or can someone point out the documentation for understanding the GObject Metadata model. What should I do to get a list of the available tags?

Comment: If it's a dictionary(-like) object, `exif.keys()` should give you a list of keys in it.

Comment: See [`GExiv2.py`](https://github.com/robru/gexiv2/blob/master/GExiv2.py) for the source of the Python Metadata API. `get_tags()` looks interesting ;-)

Comment: Thanks, `exif.keys()` won't work, but you can check the available tags with `print exif.get_tags()` and get e.g. the camera model with `exif['Exif.Image.Model']`.

Answer (score 0):

To expand what's posted in comments, the `get_tags()` function will return a list of the tags in the metadata. So you can do, for example:

```
exif = GExiv2.Metadata(testfile)
if 'Exif.Photo.Make' in exif.get_tags():
    print exif['Exif.Photo.Make']
```